# Mission Control - dragging to move spaces between multiple monitors

Tags: macos, virtual-desktop, osx-spaces, mission-control, macos-sonoma

In MacOS Sonoma, I use two external monitors, positioned side by side.  If I enter Mission Control (by swiping up on my trackpad with three fingers) then all the virtual desktops ('spaces') become visible at the top of the monitors.

Whilst in Mission Control mode, sometimes I am able to drag the icon representing the space/Desktop from one monitor to the other.  Other times, when I try to drag the icon, it will not leave the boundary at the edge of the monitor.

This behaviour seems intermittent, almost random.  What factors determine whether the icon representing the space can be dragged between monitors?